# What is the best way to test if nested list is as expected?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, ruby-on-rails-4

When running a unit test, I'm expecting a method I am testing to return a nested array like this:

```
[
{:identifier=>"a", :label=>"a label", 
    :sublist=>[{:identifier=>"sublist z", :label=>"z sublist label"}, {:identifier=>" sublist w", :label=>"sublist w label"}]}, 
{:identifier=>"b", :label=>"b label", 
    :sublist=>[{:identifier=>"sublist y", :label=>"y sublist label"}]}, 
..]
```

What is the most elegant way to check if the array returned is what I expect it to be?

I'm using Minitest Spec if that makes any difference.

Btw, the order of elements does not matter and may vary.

Thx.

Comment: Is it just the top-level elements that can be reordered (that is, `b` could be before `a`); or can sublist be reordered (this is, `w` could be before `z`)?

Comment: @Chowlett b can be before a, w could be before z and :identifier could be before :label.

Comment: `:identifier` and `:label` don't matter - hashes are unordered anyway, so they'll compare equal regardless of the "order". The reordering of the nested list is trickier...

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it would be ideal to write a `custom matcher` for `minitest`.
Here, is the code that you would need to add in the matcher.

```
def match_hash(h1, h2)
  matched = false
  h1.each do |ele|
    h2.each do |ele2|
      match_elements?(ele, ele2) ? (matched = true) : next
    end
    if !matched
      return matched
    end
  end
  matched
end

def match_elements?(ele, ele2)
  if (ele[:identifier] != ele2[:identifier]) || (ele[:label] != ele2[:label])
    return false
  end
  if ele.has_key?(:sublist) && ele2.has_key?(:sublist)
    return match_hash(ele[:sublist], ele2[:sublist])
  end
  true
end
```

Write your custom matcher [using this example](http://jkotests.wordpress.com/2013/12/02/comparing-arrays-in-an-order-independent-manner-using-minitest/)
Then use `match_hash` in your test case to compare the two hashes.

NOTE: The above code has been tested in irb and it works perfectly.

Comment: @vrepsys No problem. Let me know if you come across any issues in the code.